# azure media services encoding

Tags: encoding, azure-media-services

I use Azure Media services v2 and I use custom media encoding configuration from json. My JSON includes three sizes, 720p, 480p and 180p.

I want to convert based on uploaded video sizes. If I upload a 1080p video it need to be converted to 720p, 480p and 180p, but when I upload a video of 480p it needs to be encoded to only 480p and 180p. Unfortunately, Azure media services upscales the video to 720p, as this is specified in the encoder configuraiton.

How do I achieve this?

Should I dynamically form the configuration depending on the uploaded asset?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is similar to 'Adaptive Streaming' preset for Media Encoder Standard.  Info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-autogen-bitrate-ladder-with-mes.  Currently Media Services does not allow you to specify the different encoding settings within the *Adaptive Streaming* bitrate ladder.
This means that if you want to only ever have a possibility of 3 bitrates you would need to determine the resolutions you want prior to the encode job and use a different encoding profile based on the input video.

Comment: Yes what i want is to avoid scaling up the uploaded video. Is that possible?